# Is the Cloud Function for Firebase unavailable when the function is updated

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When I am updating a Cloud Function for Firebase using the CLI `firebase deploy --only functions`, is the Function unavailable for a certain amount of time or is that handled by the Cloud Function infrastructure internally and the Function is available at all times and it just switches over to the new Function once the deployment is successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Functions is in beta, and Google currently does not give any guarantees about the availability of your code.  But the intent is that you should not miss any invocations when replacing the code.  There has been [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/g2QIBe1Sy1M/S0YHNlGbBgAJ) about this already.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The link to discussion was helpful.